# Spring webflux - How to use rsql queries inside a spring reactive app using R2DBC?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming, r2dbc, rsql, r2dbc-mssql

I’m working on a reactive Java spring web app using webflux.
I’m trying to convert rsql queries received as a param within the endpoint URL.
I managed to get the details of this queries converted to Specification object that usually would be then used to query the database with JPA but as I’m not using JPA but webflux and R2DBC, I need to get a org.springframework.data.relational.core.sql.Comparison object instead.
Can’t figure out how to do so.
Any ideas on how to use rsql string query inside an R2DBC using app ?

Many thanks

I tried to convert the Specification object into a Comparison object. I tried to build a customRsqlVisitor class …

Comment: `managed to get the details of this queries converted to Specification object that usually would be then used to query the database with JPA but as I’m not using JPA` --> R2DBC stands for Reactive JDBC.

Comment: Hi, I know of course but then what does it change concerning my problem ?

Comment: Hi. rsql seems to be based on a 9 year old pet project that doesn't seem to support generating sql from the REST parameters. I think problem trying to use this 9 year old project in the first place.